# Creating a carousel-like form using CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, frontend, carousel

I'm, just wondering what the best approach is to create a carousel form like the one shown [Here](https://billysumo.com.au/combined/lander/energyhealthsave?my_state_is=Victoria&reference_number=&source=taboola_lp_energyhealthsave&source_id=H517&transaction_id=102c12d3eac7edfad05970f8bc9c59&page_variant=VariantA&sub_id=taboola1&ad_set=native)
 is. For further explanation, I am looking to create a form where users may input some information, Click next, a transition of some sort will happen, and the form will change to different inputs without leaving the page, similar to a carousel.

Comment: I can show you multiple solutions to this but I feel you are not gonna like it, so make a research first on the internet. then if you try some code and breaks or even don't work you can show us your code and we will try to help you

Comment: You can search `template form wizard` and read about it.